# How to repair the color?

Tags: shaders, color

My model was changed by another person.

The cloth border color changed to blue.

I want repair green.

How to repair it?
Why changed?
[image]
blue Bad color.
[image]

[image]
Green correct color
[image]

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer to make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

The material are not the same, they don't have the same *Image Texture*, as you can see in your blue file, the material called *cloth.008* has a blue stroke image affected:

[image]

To fix it, select the image *atlas_equipment_blue.003* instead:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know really why, but for some reason the Principled shader is interpreted differently between the two, even though they are seemingly the same, and even after I tried to perfectly match the shader and all options I could think in other places.

Maybe the person that changed your model used a different Blender version where the Principled BSDF shader was different, and it somehow corrupted the file.

---

In any case, you can append the material you need:

1. Open the file blue.blend
2. Go in the menu File > Append:
   [image: menu]
3. Navigate to green.blend > Materials, select `cloth.005` and click the blue <kbd>Append</kbd> button:
   [image: append]
4. Select your model
5. In the Properties Editor > Material tab, click the <kbd>-</kbd> button to remove all material slots except one:
   [image: material slots]
6. Click the Material list drop down and select `cloth.005`:
   [image: material list]

The final result should be this:

[image: final]

Additionally, I encourage you to rename your material into something clearer like "MAT_Cloth_Green", and also purge the other material duplicates and texture files if you don't need them.
For this, go to the menu File > Cleanup > Recursive Unused Data-Blocks:

[image: purge]

This way, you will no longer have tons of duplicated materials and texture files that to the same thing, you will have a cleaner file, and also lighter:

[image: lighter file]

Comment: I tried to do that but there are no c loth.005.
And I tried to search atlas_equipment_blue.png
But there can not choose png data.
And, I tried to append a green file folder.
But It appears to be an error.
The message is "not a library".
What is wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer to detail the procedure, please try again and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I could do it that way.
Sorry really late.
And thanks.